# Eliminar filas con macro en excel

Tags: excel, macros

Quiero eliminar las filas que contengan datos de las columnas A y B, para eso desarrolle una macro, corre  y no marca ningun error pero no borra las celdas

¿Que puedo estar haciendo mal?

```
Sub Limpiar()
Dim Celda As Range, UltimaFila As Long
UltimaFila = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each Celda In Range("A2:B" & UltimaFila)
If (Celda.Value = "") Then Celda.ClearContents
Next Celda
End Sub
```

[image: Filas que quiero eliminar]

Comment: *Quiero eliminar las filas que contengan datos*. Pero en tu código pones `If (Celda.Value = "") Then Celda.ClearContents` y eso lo que hace es que si la celda está en blanco, borra el valor (pero no borra la fila, ojo). Prueba con `If Not Celda.Value = "" Then Celda.ClearContents` aunque si lo que quieres es simplemente borrar el contenido de todas las celdas, es más rápido si haces `Range("A2:B" & UltimaFila).ClearContents`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba así:

```
Sub Limpiar()
Dim UltimaFila As Long
UltimaFila = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:B" & UltimaFila).ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: Procura siempre explicar por qué el código que sugieres resuelve la pregunta y cómo debería usarse.

Answer (score 2):

Gracias al comentario de @Elier Sanchez, esta linea era la que tenia mal `If (Celda.Value = "")`

Funciona el codigo de esta manera

```
Sub Limpiar()
Dim Celda As Range, UltimaFila As Long
UltimaFila = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each Celda In Range("A2:B" & UltimaFila)
Celda.ClearContents
Next Celda
End Sub
```

Comment: No necesitas hacer un bucle para esto. Con poner `Range("A2:B" & UltimaFila).ClearContents` se borrarían todas, que es justo lo que estás haciendo ahora, pero de 1 en 1.